# Checking weather default value of DropDownList changed or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DropDownList with values

```
1.--select one--
2.one
3.two
4.three
```

Now I want to know whether user have changed the default value of DropDownList or not.Currently I am hard coding the values like this

```
if(ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text !="--Select One--")
```

I don't think this is a good practice as I have a lot of DropDownLists like this in my page and some will be binded dynamically..Can any one give me the best practice?

Comment: well you can check the selected value on dropdown selected changed index and store in varidable. whenever user select other option from drop down, this event fire and you have to compare with store value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if this is the best practice, but default values are the first itmes in DropDownLists hence this check: `ddlCountry.SelectedIndex > 0` should suffice for all dropdowns.

Answer (score 3):

When I was faced with a similar problem, I used the `Value` property for all other items BUT the default.

Then I would check

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dropDown.SelectedItem.Value))
{  }
```

This assumes the default value might not be the first on the dropdown - which it is in the majority of cases, but other people have already got that case covered. ;)

Answer (score 1):

What about using

```
if(ddlCountry.SelectedIndex != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

What others have said should be good enough, but it would be even better if you give your default option a value - say `-1` or `Select` or something like that and then check -

```
if(ddlWithDefault.SelectedItem.Value != "-1" && ddlWithDefault.SelectedItem.Value.ToLower() != "select")
{
   // Do your thing here...
}
```